# Is $\lceil  2l/3 \rceil = l - \lfloor l/3 \rfloor$?

Tags: calculus

Is $\lceil 2l/3 \rceil = l - \lfloor l/3 \rfloor$? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Presumably $\ell$ is supposed to be an integer, since the other two terms in your equation are.  Hint: try the three cases $\ell \equiv 0, 1, 2 \mod 3$.